# Is it possible to dock the "Find/Replace" window in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, replace, find, window, docking

I could have sworn I saw it once before in a screencast where someone had the find/replace window docked in their Eclipse environment.

However looking through the list of options in "Window > Show" the closest thing I can find is the Search window.

I find that I use it quite a bit and with larger monitors these days I figure I could afford to have it open in my perspective all the time.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: There is this plugin [Glance](http://ystrot.github.io/glance/) which adds incremental search to the status bar (not a dockable view though)

Comment: I too wish for this ability. I run in full-screen mode on a high-resolution monitor and find that I need to place the find/replace dialog on another monitor which is far from ideal. Other IDEs let you do this and I really like it.

Comment: You can do this installing the plugin [Find Bar](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/find-bar-eclipse "Find Bar for Eclipse"). ![Find Bar plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/sites/default/files/styles/ds_solution_screenshot/public/FindReplaceBar.png) Once you enable the current Find/replace dialog overriding, it replaces the dialog by a view that allows to find text but does not replace text. The standard dialog is still accessible.

Answer (score 8):

One poor-man's workaround is to dock a view that you don't need in a part of Eclipse where you want the find/replace view and then place the find/replace dialog on top of that like this:

[image]

Clearly this is a huge kludge but it does work.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about that, since [Fast views are](http://wiki.eclipse.org/UIGraphics_:_Specifications_:_GraphicTypes):

> icons allowing users to quickly display different **views** that have been created as fast views

[image]

And the search/replace is a [Dialog](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/dialogs.htm), not a [View](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-5.htm)..

[image]
<sub>(source: [bpsite.net](https://bpsite.net/misc/eclipse_replace.png))</sub>

(That Dialog box is not like Views, which support editors, also have their own menus. Some views also have their own toolbars.)

The [help page mentions](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-21.htm):

> Fast views are hidden views that can be quickly opened and closed. They work like other views except they do not take up space in your Workbench window.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be an exact answer for the question. But this works like a charm.

- Press ctrl + j and keep typing...
- Use ctrl + k to go on
- Use shift key wherever required.

Use **Edit > Incremental Find Next (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)** or **Edit > Incremental Find Previous (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)** to enter the incremental find mode, and start typing the string to match. Matches are found incrementally as you type. The search string is shown in the status line. Press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>** or **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>** to go to the next or previous match. Press **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** or **<kbd>Esc</kbd>** to exit incremental find mode.